# Is Office 2010 supported by SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, office

Is Office 2010 (client)  supported by SharePoint 2016?

I can't find this in any technet article

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know SharePoint 2016 support the office 2010(it is backward compatible). I am running a large deployment of SharePoint 2016 and 70% of our user using the office 2010 but no major issue reported to us so far.

Answer (score -1):

Say thank you to Microsoft Press :)

Check the following links for details

https://goo.gl/4jEJRU

Book reference here :

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780735699250